# Gratis form builder

Tags: windows, gratis, html, forms

I am looking for a gratis, drag & drop form builder and processor (Web based or Windows, possibly Android).

**Form builder**

let's imagine a doctor's surgery wants to let  patients book appointments online (but the app should be generic & handle other type of form/survey).

The user (doctor) should be able to drag & drop standard form components, such as:

- text box
- text memo
- numerical input box
- list box
- drop down combo box
- mutually exclusive radio buttons
- checkboxes
- date / time picker
- button (for "save")

nice to have

- spinners, sliders, 5 star voting, etc

**Form processing**

let's imagine the patient wants to book an appointment.

The generated form should be runnable in the browser I.e HTML plus some Js

Output is a bit trickier, but I can run up some code to massage it into any desired format.

I can't see that CSV makes sense. Maybe XML? Maybe writing directly to a database? How do these things normally work?

It might be nice to have the form save button also send email or SMS/etc, in addition to generating an output file.

Any ideas? The more bells & whistles, the better

Comment: try [JQuery Form Builder](https://formbuilder.online/)

Comment: I thought for a moment that I would have to ask "the doctor" to go there to build their form, but - no - it looks like I add it into my own app or web site and "the doctor" uses that to design a form, which is just what I wanted. So, please post that as an answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a practical solution and aware of you wouldn't improve your coding much:

**An option (online):**

[JQuery formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/)

[image: JQuery formBuilder screenshot]

**An option (windows program, regarding your kind words)**

[CoffeeCup Web Form Builder](https://www.coffeecup.com/web-form-builder/)

[image: CoffeeCup Web Form Builder]

For saving, state whether you use php or asp, payment requirement, output format and web based / own host. Please mark this answer as solved if it's useful.

Comment: I really like th look of JQuery form builder. However, despite having read the documentation, I still can’t figure it out. Once the doctor has defined the form, how do they save to, for loading  to their web site? And, once the patient has filled out an appointment form, how does the data get saved, and where?